# Convert text box into dropdown in Synfusion ejs dotnet core

Tags: .net, syncfusion, ej2-syncfusion

I am new to dotnet core syncfusion, I want to change highlighted textbox into dropdown in below image,
I tried with "ejs-dropdown tag" but that is a dotnet core tag helper, which will run in server. But below one is inside script which will be executed in client side.
[image]